# how to store one table primary as an another table foreign key using one-to-one relationship

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have two entities with one to one relationship, I want parent entity primary as a child entity foreign key along with child entity primary key

I have been trying with JPA @MapsId() but I could not succeed

my parent entity

```
 @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(initialValue=10000, name = "parent_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
     generator="parent_seq")
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private long parentid;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="parentEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ChildEntity childEntity;


    and in my child entity 



         @SequenceGenerator(initialValue=10000, name = "child_seq")
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
            generator="child_seq")
            @Column(name = "child_id")
            private long childid;

            @MapsId("parent_id")
            @OneToOne
            private ParentEntity parentEntity;
```

here I would like to create tables using JPA for that I have given
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
this is working fine but I am expecting that parent_id column should be created inside my childEntity table but it is not creating and the parent_id should be inserted into child tables parent_id column.

Comment: did you try to find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to use `@MapsId` feature then your 'child' entity should have the 'simple' identifier without any generation. For example:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private Long id;
    // other stuff...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "children")
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;

    // other stuff...
}
```

In this case, the `children` table will be like the following:

```sql
create table children (
  parent_id bigint not null constraint children_pkey primary key,
  -- other stuff...
  constraint fk_children_parent_id foreign key (parent_id) references parents(id)
);
```

More info: [The best way to map a @OneToOne relationship with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: thanks Cepr for your valuable Ans, adding a bit clarity to my question, i  am saving my parent as parent.setChild(childEntity); repository.save(parentEntity). here i am expecting  child table should get my parent id in one column and i want a primary key as well in side child table which is auto-generated with some seq generation. i agree that if use MapsId i should not use auto generation, but the thing is i need both, so plz clarify